# Dates not changing within openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I have a dataset where I am creating a graph using openpyxl. I have different dates within my dataset, however when I create this within openpyxl, the dates are fixed on January 1. Also, all of my categories are the same color. How would I change this?

Data

```
Date        Computer    Network Cables  Other
2021-02-05  2646        3000    500     1202
2021-03-07  1500        2000    3000    2000
2021-04-03  5000        2500    6000    4599
```

Desired

I'd like the dates to reflect:

```
02/02/2021
03/07/2021
04/03/2021
```

[image]

Doing:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.chart import BarChart, Reference, Series,ScatterChart, LineChart
from openpyxl.styles import Font, colors, Alignment, Border
from openpyxl.chart.axis import DateAxis

path = "C:/Users/wb1.xlsx"
wb_obj = load_workbook(path)
sheet_obj = wb_obj.active

c1 = BarChart()
c1.title = "Month Over Month Charges "
c1.y_axis.title = "Cost in Dollars"
c1.x_axis.title = "Date"
c1.style = 12
c1.x_axis.number_format = 'd-mmm'
c1.x_axis.majorTimeUnit = "days"

dates = Reference(sheet_obj, min_col=1, min_row=2, max_row=4)
c1.set_categories(dates)

data = Reference(sheet_obj, min_col=2, min_row=1, max_col=5, max_row=4)
c1.add_data(data, titles_from_data=True)

sheet_obj.add_chart(c1, "I2")
wb_obj.save("samples4.xlsx")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.chart import BarChart, Reference, Series, ScatterChart, LineChart
from openpyxl.styles import Font, colors, Alignment, Border
from openpyxl.chart.axis import DateAxis
from copy import deepcopy

path = "C:/Users/tanisha.hudson/wb1.xlsx"
wb_obj = load_workbook(path)
sheet_obj = wb_obj.active

c1 = BarChart()
c1.title = "Month Over Month Charges "
c1.y_axis.title = "Cost in Dollars"
c1.x_axis.title = "Date"
c1.style = 12
c1.x_axis.number_format = 'd-mmm'

c1.x_axis.majorTimeUnit = "days"


data = Reference(sheet_obj, min_col=2, min_row=1, max_col=5, max_row=4)
c1.add_data(data, titles_from_data=True)

dates = Reference(sheet_obj, min_col=1, min_row=2, max_row=4)
c1.set_categories(dates)

sheet_obj.add_chart(c1, "I2")
wb_obj.save("samples10.xlsx")
```